# Cut a combined path along pair of non-connected nodes in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

I have a hollow closed path created by taking two closed paths and applying Path > Difference. I know the two paths are "identical", but one is an inset of the other. (This could be done with one of the Path > Offset tools, but that ends up creating curves I don't want, so I created this one by duplicating my closed path, giving the duplicate a wide stroke, Path > Stroke to Path, Path > Break Apart, delete outer path.)

I want to take matched pairs of these points and "cut" the shape into pieces. I've marked where I want the cuts with short red lines

[image]

Is there a straightforward way to make these cuts, yielding 4 non-hollow paths that together make up the original hollow path.

I can use Path > Cut Path with something like this, using the red path for the cut...

[image]

But that breaks the hollow path into the two original paths and I end up spending a bunch of time going node-pair by node-pair re-stitching a bunch of open paths back into closed ones.

Here's after I've make 2 of the 4 cuts and stitched together one of the 4 closed paths I eventually want. (I pulled it apart for illustrative purposes; they were all adjacent on initial cut as expected.)

[image]

All of this feels suspiciously fiddly, like I'm manually doing something that Inkscape can do for me. I'd hoped that in "Edit paths by nodes" I could select the two relevant nodes and one of the toolbar buttons would break each of the nodes into two, then link the pairs of nodes to each other, re-closing path (and possibly splitting the path into two paths).

"Break path at selected nodes" followed by selecting pairs of nodes and "Join selected nodes with a new segment" seems promising, but is still what seems like a lot of busy work, and I don't know how I can reliably select the right pairs so I get two ends as opposed to an overlap like this:

[image]

Is there an easy, or at least easier, way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close with the red path, but instead of 'Path → Cut Path' you want to use 'Path → Division'. This will cut the *area* of a path (instead of just path-segments) with another path like a cookie-cutter.

[image: Dividing Shape]

Also make sure to enable snapping and snapping to nodes to place the red path exactly on the nodes of your original shape.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected I was missing something obvious, and apparently I was. I gave it a try and it did exactly what I wanted!